# session undefined using MemoryStore

Tags: node.js, session, express, socket.io

I'm trying use sessions in socket.io using MemoryStore but when I try to obtain the session I get a undefined object. This is my code

**DEPENDENCIES**

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var connect = require('connect');
var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io');
var MemoryStore = express.session.MemoryStore;
```

**CONFIGURATION**

```
sessionStore = new MemoryStore();
var SITE_SECRET = 'I am not wearing any pants';
var sessionStore = new connect.session.MemoryStore();
app.use(express.cookieParser(SITE_SECRET));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.session({secret: "This is a secret", key: 'express.sid', store: sessionStore}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   app.locals.pretty = true;
   next();
});
```

**SOCKET.IO**

```
sio.set('authorization', function (data, accept) {
    if (data.headers.cookie) {
        data.cookie = require('cookie').parse(data.headers.cookie);
        data.sessionID = data.cookie['express.sid'];
        sessionStore.get(data.sessionID, function(err, session) {
          console.log(session); //THIS GIVE ME A UNDEFINED OBJECT
        });
    } else {
       return accept('No cookie transmitted.', false);
    }
    accept(null, true);
});
```

EDIT:

If I do a `console.log(sessionStore.sessions);` I get this

```
{ p_KmCvoW6MKAFxbsxULICmrQ: '{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"loged":true,"username":"kemical","nombre":"Hector","apellido":"Gutierrez","bio":"Nací en La Rioja en el 1993","pais":"Espana","fecha_nacimiento":null,"puesto":"Diseñador Grafico","web":"http://www.kemical.es","url_avatar":"assets/img/profile/kemical"}' }
```

But I don't know how to access to that attributes.

Comment: use console.log(err); before logging the session to see if there's error or not

Comment: I get an undefined object too.